# How to use variables in inline HTML Style tag

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to get the "left" and "top" attributes to be set to the value gotten from "randomXValue" and "randomYValue" the two functions return integers.

```
randomXValue = getRandomXValue();
randomYValue = getRandomYValue();

$("#gamespace").append(
    '<img src="img/img.jpg" class="gameimg" style = "left: (randomXValue)px; top:
        (randomYValue)px;"/>'
);
```

if I put in an integer instead of the randomValue it will display in the correct location. I am trying to get the image to appear at a random location in the "#gamespace"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note the order in which the quotes are placed.

In your example, we start with single quotes, which are used to define the start and end of the string. To insert variables into the string, we can split the string by inserting a single quote at any point and concatenate the variable with the string using the plus sign.

You have to insert the variable as follows

```
randomXValue = getRandomXValue();
randomYValue = getRandomYValue();

$("#gamespace").append(
    '<img src="img/img.jpg" class="gameimg" style = "left: "'+randomXValue+'"px; top:"'+randomYValue+'"px;"/>'
);
```

Comment: Up vote as this does work, but see @naveen answer for modern solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for readability

```js
const left = getRandomXValue();
const top = getRandomYValue();
$("#gamespace").append(
    `<img src="img/img.jpg" class="gameimg" style="left:${left}px;top:${top}px;"/>`
);
```